# Push col-md-6 div to next row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout:

[image]

and I want the highlighted div to be moved to the next row, right below "Number of seats", so I thought adding a "col-md-offset-6" to it would place it just fine. However, the result is this:

[image]

Code:

```
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-top: 15px;">
        <label class="control-label">@Localizer.GetWebTranslation("Locations", "Number of seats")</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfSeats, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 70px", @data_bind = "value : NumberOfSeats" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 30px">
        <input data-bind="checked: Terrace" id="checkbox-4" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-4" type="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox-4" class="checkbox-custom-label control-label">@Localizer.GetWebTranslation("Products", "Terrace")</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 15px">
        <label class="control-label">@Localizer.GetWebTranslation("LocationProfile", "Location Profiles")</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="profilesAutocomplete" data-bind="textInput: $root.SelectedProfileName" placeholder="@Localizer.GetWebTranslation("Locations", "Search.. (e.g. Catering, Vinery)")" />
    </div>
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: set the number of seats div to 12 columns instead

Comment: @j08691 the "numberofseats" and "terrace" divs are each "col-md-3"'s. Added code.

Comment: So make numberofseats 3 cols and terrace 9

Comment: you need the div to be right above the "Number of seats" or below it ?

Comment: @AswinKallikadavil below, sorry, edited.

Comment: "The right way to do this" is an opinionated answer. You should simply explain how your current outcome differs from your desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the row classed divs as follow

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="city" class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div id="country" class="col-md-6"></div>
   .
   .
   .
   <div id="NumberOfSeats" class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div id="LocationProfiles" class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"> City </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">country</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"> Street Name</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Zip Code</div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"> Email</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Phone</div>
</div>  .
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">Number Of seat</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Terrace</div>
   <div class=col-md-6"></div>`**...(optional)**`
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">Location profile</div>
</div>
```

This is the right way to structure this form using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

in last div of location profile just add in css clear:left;